# Can I add a subview inside a subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, addsubview

I have added a view inside ViewController using `[self.view addSubview:newView]`. newView is a UIView type object.
Inside newView I added added a few views using `[self addSubview:polyg];`.
`Polygs` also inherit from `UIView`. But they never get drawn. `drawRect:(CGRect)rect` is never called.

I'm new to iOS and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

It probably has something to do with the fact that I did not use `self.view` when adding views to newView. I can't even use `self.view` inside newView.

how can I make this work?

edit:
When i create these polyg objects I'm using initWithFrame and sending newView's frame, like this: `[[Polyg alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];` 
Could this be the cause? Polyg is going to be a movable and resizable polygon, so I figured each should be able to draw on the entire screen.

edit:
I created a method inside newView called touchX:Y that is called from the viewController whenever I touch my finger on the screen. Inside I wrote this: NSLog(@"subview = %i", self.subviews.count);. Whenever I touch the screen I see this on the console: subview = 89 so I'm pretty sure the subviews were added to newView.

I tried adding this to the same touchX:Y method:

```
        for (UIView* subview in self.subviews) {
            [subview setNeedsDisplay];
        }
```

But the subviews' drawRect is never called.

Comment: You can add nested subviews as deep as you need. Just remember that a view's frame is always relative to its immediate superview (parent view).

Comment: Yes, you can add subviews to subviews.  If you really called your method `DrawRect`, it won't get called.  The name of the method must be `drawRect:`.  It must be correctly capitalized and must take one `CGRect` argument.  If you did call it `drawRect:`, how do you know it's not being called?

Comment: - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    NSLog(@"drawRect!");
}
drawRect never shows up on the console. (edited the question with the correct method name)

Comment: If *newView* is a view, it hasn't a property called *view*. View controllers have it.

Comment: It is a view and I can't use self.view inside it. Is that the problem? I can add subViews to the viewController but can't add a subView to a subView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely possibility is that newView is either completely off the screen or have a size of (0,0). Right before you add the ployg subviews, use the debugger to print out the frame of newView.

Comment: I added a breakpoint but could not find the frame (tried the search box)

Comment: that seems to be the problem. `NSLog(@"frame size x/y = %f/%f", self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);` resulted in `frame size x/y = 0.000000/0.000000` on the console. 

I created the newView like this:

Comment: in the debugger, type in this:
"po self.frame"

Comment: use debugger = add a break point and check the variables area next to the console area?

Comment: There are two areas. Use the one that shows the application log.

Comment: Just FYI, `po self.frame` won't work, but `p self.frame` should work in recent versions of Xcode.  In code, the easiest way to log a `CGRect` (like `self.frame`) is `NSLog(@"frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame))`.